# The order of an element in a group

Tags: group-theory

I am looking for an element of order 5 in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$, but I cannot find one.  Just to clarify, I believe $\mathbb{Z}_{24} = \left\{ 1,2,3,...,23\right\}$, is this correct?  Additionally, I believe that the order of an element $g$ in a group is defined as the smallest positive integer $n$ where $g^{n} = e$, and $e$ is the identity element.

$e$ for $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ would be 1 because 1 times any element in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ gives back the element.  I don't think there is a $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ that is not $e$ for which $g^{5} = 1$?

Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Z24 includes 0 as an element.
2) Your definiton of order is correct.
3) If an element has order 5, then x+x+x+x+x=0 mod 24, and this should be the smallest n auch that when x is added n times, it is 0. The equation implies x is 0 (e). But the order of e is 1. So there is no element of order 5.
Also, you are working with the additive group mod 24 - the set is not a group under multiplication, so the identity is 0, and addition is "multiplication".

Comment: Was I incorrect to say that Z24 = {1,2,3,4,...,23}?  When Z24 should have been {1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23}?

Comment: @PiccolMan If you wanted the multiplicative group of units mod 24, then you denote it as $\Bbb{Z}^x_{24}$. Then it is the set ${1,5,7,11,13,17,\color{19}{blue},23}$ that has multiplication as a group operation.

Comment: Oh I see.  Also, why did you add $blue$ to the list?

Comment: @PiccolMan then as the order of the group of units is 8, and the order of an elemnt has to divide the order of the griup, there is no element of order 5.

Comment: @PiccolMan As you did not include 19 in your list, I added it and tried to emphasize it with a blue color, but my latex failed (i think, i cannot see on mobile)

Answer (score 2):

No, $\mathbb Z_{24}$ is an **additive** group and contains the element zero. What you are looking here are numbers $k$ such $5k\equiv 0\mod 24$.

Comment: How would one know if a group is additive or multiplicative?

Comment: In principle it is just notation, but $\mathbb Z_{24}$, even if you remove zero, is not a group. as a ring, It has divisors of zero: for instance $2\times 12=0$, so they cannot have multiplicative inverses.